# What's the difference between STATUS_FLOAT_MULTIPLE_FAULTS and STATUS_FLOAT_MULTIPLE_TRAPS?

Tags: windows, x86, sse, seh

When an unmasked SSE exception happens the processor raises a SIMD floating point exception. This is a fault type exception, so EIP stays on the instruction that caused the exception.

This exception is translated to one of the status codes above.

What's the difference between the two?